# Adobe Animate: How to make nested movie clip symbols autoplay and loop

Tags: adobe-animate

This should be an easy question but through all my searching I cannot find anyone who even so much as mentions this: I want to make a movie clip symbol autoplay. If a symbol is a graphic then it autoplays and loops. Ok, fine. But, once I convert it to a movie clip symbol, it doesn't autoplay and I don't know why. It just stays on the first frame indefinitely.

I've tried this multiple times in different projects. You can see what I mean by creating movie clip symbol, put something in it on its own timeline and drag the symbol on to your main stage timeline. It always stays on the first frame. Can only graphic symbols animate automatically? Do I need some scripting to start it? I can see no properties for autoplaying.

Comment: That sounds horribly wrong. The default **MovieClip** behavior is auto-play, it should be explicitly stopped to not to. There could be few reasons though what you could do to achieve the described behavior. 1. Select your designed object on Stage and call its properties (**not** the Library properties). If the behavior is set to **Graphic** and **single frame**, then Flash ignores the fact it is a **MovieClip** in Library. 2. You put it on the main timeline as a sequence of keyframes. Each keyframe re-creates the object anew and it is on the frame 1.

Comment: 3. You don't **Ctrl+Enter** run/test the movie but rather **Enter** preview it as designed. The thing is, **MovieClip** is a runtime-only behavior, in design/preview time they are displayed in their initial state which is frame 1.